# Как сделать такие линии?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

каким образом можно сделать такие линии? И имеют ли они вообще какое-то общепринятое название? Не первый раз вижу
Если есть то скиньте пример[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLMQaoV - если с чем то возникнут проблемы - напишите мне об этом

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)